# Get data from realm database?

Tags: android, realm

I am looking to use a Realm database for my android application.
My problem is when I want to get the data from the database I get some strange extras, for example I get the names of the Strings in my class.

Here is how I get my data:

```
    RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this).build();
    realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    RealmResults<timeData> result = realm.where(timeData.class).findAll();

    listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0;i<result.size();i++){
        data.add(result.toString());
    }

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,data);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And this is what i get from the **result.toString** when adding it to my **ArrayList**:

> > [timeData = [{id:null},{cars:3},{accident:null},{bears:null},{s:null},{mile:null}]]

**UPDATE**

Here is code how the data is saved to the database:

```
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    realm.beginTransaction();
    timeData data = realm.createObject(timeData.class);
    data.setCars(editTextCar);
    realm.commitTransaction();
```

timeData is a class that extends the Realm.

Comment: So those null values are not expected? Can you please also share the code for saving them into the db?

Comment: @beeender check my update. The null values is because I dont give them any. Is there another way to get the data?

Comment: OK, I guess i have some misunderstanding. So you actually implemented the `TimeData.toString()` to return the name and it returns something you don't expect, right? The thing is, Realm will create a Proxy class for all the tricks, and the proxy class is overwriting the `toString()` method. So you might try to use a different method name than `toString()` to return the name, maybe `getNameString()`?

Comment: Woah that did the trick. I made a **getter** thar return a **String** with the data and it worked really nice.